# Subversion: Migrating from cloud SVN repo to local SVN repo... lost history?

Tags: svn, version-control, migration

I created my own SVN repo locally. Then used:

```
svnsync init DEST SRC
svnsync sync DEST
svnsync checkout DEST
```

The checkout worked successfully and I got all the files from the original SVN repo and that is definitely a good thing!

But when I did:

```
svn log
```

All I get is the message:

```
svn: Item is not readable
```

**Does the file not have any history?**

**Did I migrate the SVN repo incorrectly?**

I followed the instructions I found as best as I could...

---

p.s. FWIW here is the commands I executed in the form of a bash shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#===============================================================================
#= Function: Script to migrate an old svn repository to a new svn repository
#= Purpose:  The process is kinda tricky... need to write it down to prevent 
#=           reinventing the wheel
#===============================================================================

# User input parameters for this script
DEFAULT_REPO_PATH = "srv/svn/repos";
NEW_REPO_NAME = "name";
SRC_REPOSITORY_URL = "https://example.googlecode.com/svn";

# Create the folder for all your svn repositories before creating the repository
sudo mkdir --parents /$(DEFAULT_REPO_PATH)/$(NEW_REPO_NAME)/

# Create the new repository
sudo svnadmin create /$(DEFAULT_REPO_PATH)/$(NEW_REPO_NAME)/

# -- The new repository is not ready for receiving the old repository.
# -- There are a number of actions that need to be completed before you can 
#    load the old repository onto the new repository.

# 1.) Setup the pre-revprop-change hook
cd /$(DEFAULT_REPO_PATH)/$(NEW_REPO_NAME)/hooks/
sudo touch pre-revprop-change
sudo chmod +x pre-revprop-change

# 2.) Eventually we are calling svnsync init $(SRC_URL) $(SRC_URL) but 
#     the new repository is not accessible via any URL because there is 
#     no server setup 
#     
#     Example URLS:
#     -- svn://$(SERVER)/$(SRC_REPO_NAME)
#     -- ssh+svn://$(SERVER)/$(SRC_REPO_NAME)
#     -- https://$(SERVER)/$(SRC_REPO_NAME)
#
#     To make the new repository accesible via URL I will setup an svn 
#     server using the built in "svnserve" command.
#
#     Svnserve command line switches:
#     -d, --daemon
#         Causes svnserve to  run  in  daemon  mode.   svnserve  backgrounds
#         itself  and  accepts and serves TCP/IP connections on the svn port
#         (3690, by default).
#     -r root, --root=root
#         Sets the virtual root for repositories served  by  svnserve.   The
#         pathname  in URLs provided by the client will be interpreted rela‐
#         tive to this root, and will not be allowed to escape this root.
svnserve -d -r /$(DEFAULT_REPO_PATH)/

# 3.) Almost ready, the last step is to give write permission to the new repository
#    
#     By default a new repository is read only.
#
#   3.1) To give write permission you have to edit both the 
#   3.2) "svnserve.conf" and 
#   3.3) "passwd" file
#     /$(DEFAULT_REPO_PATH)/$(NEW_REPO_NAME)/conf/svnserve.conf file
sudo vim /$(DEFAULT_REPO_PATH)/$(NEW_REPO_NAME)/conf/svnserve.conf
#   3.4) uncomment: "anon-access = read"
#   3.5) uncomment: "auth-access = write"
#   3.6) uncomment: "authz-db = authz"
sudo vim /$(DEFAULT_REPO_PATH)/$(NEW_REPO_NAME)/conf/passwd
#   3.9) add a line for the new authorized user
#        "
#        $(USER1) = $(USER1_PASSWD)
#        "
#   3.10) add a line for the authorization permissions 
#         (groups... like anonymous or authorized get... or set up 
#         specific permissions for specific users or groups)
#         "
#         [/]
#         $authenticated = rw 
#         "
#   3.11) You have to enable the new svnserve settings by restarting the svn 
#         server. To do this you "kill" the svn server.
sudo kill $(PID_OF_SVNSERVE)
#   3.12) Restart the svn server by calling svnserve again
svnserve -d -r /$(DEFAULT_REPO_PATH)/

# 4.) Synchronize the new repository with the old repository
# NOTE: It took about 0.5 seconds for each revision... I only had about 
sudo svnsync init svn://$(DEFAULT_REPO_PATH)/$(NEW_REPO_NAME) $(SRC_REPOSITORY_URL)
sudo svnsync sync svn://$(DEFAULT_REPO_PATH)/$(NEW_REPO_NAME)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set up/migrate the permission settings?

Comment: Could I get a link to how to "set up/migrate the permission settings"?

Answer (score 2):

for SVN log trouble: You have bad configuration (or Subversion has a bug:)).

Anyway it can be fixed by changing in "svnserve.conf" file the line:

```
[general]
anon-access = none
```

Another solution to change only "auzh" file the line:

```
[/]
* = r
```

That solution is given anonymous reads your repository that is not good. 
If you need to use only authorization repository than use the first solution. (was tested with svn 1.6.17, but think it does not depend from version)